# Changing next.config.js variables after build

Tags: webpack, next.js

I created an application using nextjs and I used next.config.js `publicRuntimeConfig` for variables that can be changed.
I store something like Page default titles and/or my site configurations.

This application can be installed for different customers with different settings.

For example, I have an `AGENCY_NAME` property inside `publicRuntimeConfig` which is obviously different for different customers.

One can be "Company 1" and the other can be "Company 2".

I build this application once and move it to my server and then for every new customer I copy the same folder and create a host for it.

But when I try to change the variables inside the  `next.config.js` it doesn't affect the values and the value remains the same. it only takes effect if I rebuild the application which I don't want to do.

So, is it possible to make some workaround about this or are there any other ways to achieve this? I just want to have some variables that can be changed later in production.

**Note**: variables use both on server and client-side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok! I figured it out after 3 days.

here is the steps to achieve this.

1. install `dotenv` package using `npm i dotenv` or `yarn add dotenv`
2. create `.env.local` file in the project root
3. add your variables inside .env file
4. create `next.config.js` and your variables in `publicRuntimeConfig` like this

   ```
   publicRuntimeConfig: {
       FIRST_VAR: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIRST_VAR,
       SECOND_VAR: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECOND_VAR,
   }
   ```
5. create a build using `npx next build`
6. simply change `.env.local` file when you need to change the variables

honestly, I have no idea why installing dotenv package fix this. my best guess is, it changes how nextjs behave and use .env files.

Comment: The dotenv package load the environment variables from your `.env` file into the process.env scope. That's why installing the dotenv package fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I need build once, run anywhere. It's worked for me.

1. create file `public/variable.js`

```
window.FILE_PATH="XXX"
```

2. import from Head

```
<Head>
    <script src="/varaiable.js"></script>
</Head>
```

3. access by `global.FILE_PATH`

```
<span>{global.FILE_PATH}<span>
{global.FILE_PATH && <img src={global.FILE_PATH + '/logo.png'} />}
{global.FILE_PATH && <a href={global.FILE_PATH} />}
```

Change `public/variable.js` at target enviorment.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem changing env variables without having to rebuild the application. The problem is because Next.js hardcode the value at build time if the `process.env.SOMETHING` is accessed directly. A workaround to this is by dynamically accessing by a reference/variable e.g. `process.env["SOMETHING"]`.

An example in Next.js 14 using app router:

```
// file: env.tsx

import { unstable_noStore as noStore} from "next/cache";

export default function getEnv(name : string){
    noStore();
    return process.env[name];
}
```

`noStore()` is needed so that values will not be static.

page.tsx:

```
import getEnv from "./env";

export default function Page(){
    return getEnv("SOMETHING")
}
```

However this method only applies to the html returned from the server, it won't apply to the JavaScript bundle. Therefore, trying to access them in JavaScript code will always return `undefined`, as by nature variables/configs are fixed during build process and can't be changed after that.

Another way is to create an API so the client can fetch the updated data. Although, this will cost extra round trip to the server which I don't prefer it, so a workaround is to sneak these variables:

layout.tsx:

```
import getEnv from "./env";
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" data-something={getEnv("SOMETHING")}>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

To access it just `document.documentElement.dataset.something`. It's better to create a new root layout to avoid all pages being dynamically rendered.

Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser

**Note: The server must be restarted after any modifications to env variables.**

Answer (score -2):

I found some article from this [link](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2021/04/buildtime-vs-runtime-environment-variables-nextjs-docker/#using-runtime-environment-variables-client-side-or-server-side) to make you understand about runtime and buildtime variable

And after that, at least you must add `getServerSideProps` to your pages

Comment: Alvin Johanes, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Okay thank you for your suggestion. I'm new in stackoverflow