# How to disable typescript for failing my builds with nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Getting a bunch of type errors upon running `yarn next build`, for example:

`Type error: Property 'href' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }'.`

Which causes my build to fail. Is there a command i can put in my tsconfig to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Can you identify the specific line in your code where the error occurs?

Comment: Try fixing the root cause instead of fixing the symptom. Post relevant code here so that we can provide more specific resolution. Refer: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As said in official docs it should be a `next.config.js` option: `typescript: { ignoreBuildErrors: true }`, but for me it's not working actually. Another options is to get rid of all errors (not warnings) with `/* eslint-disable */` then build should work.

Answer (score 23):

From NextJS docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/ignoring-typescript-errors

Just put this lines in next.config.js under the typescript section:

```html
module.exports = {
  typescript: {
    // !! WARN !!
    // Dangerously allow production builds to successfully complete even if
    // your project has type errors.
    // !! WARN !!
    ignoreBuildErrors: true,
  },
}
```

Comment: How to do it with env variables? I want to put in in netlify deploy settings

Comment: This may be your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67851776/changing-next-config-js-variables-after-build

Answer (score -4):

just put

```
// @ts-ignore
```

in the line you want to disable type checking